# Z3's Java APIs handle quantifier variable wrongly

Tags: z3

For the following formula
    
    `(declare-fun i () Int)
    (declare-fun @I () Int)
    (declare-fun r2 () (Array Int Int))
    (assert (= i 4))
    (assert (forall ((@I Int))
    (! (=> (and (>= @I 0) (< @I i)) (= (select r2 @I) 0))
     :weight 10
     :skolemid test
     :qid test)))
    (check-sat)
    (get-model)`

The Java API returns:

`SATISFIABLE
    (define-fun i () Int 4)
    (define-fun @I () Int (- 1))`

Why it generate specific value for quantifier variable "@I"?

Answer (score 0):

Note that @I is declared twice:

```
(declare-fun @I () Int)
...
(assert (forall ((@I Int)) ...
```

Thus, it is indeed both, existential and universal. I've taken the liberty of copying this over into our [issue tracker](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/293). As discussed there, this is not a bug: "Within the term namespace, bound variables can shadow one another as well as function symbol names ..." is what the [SMT2 standard](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.5-r2015-06-28.pdf) says (Remark 2, Sec. 3.3).